# Subscribe to button click of another form

Tags: c#, event-handling, eventargs

So I have 2 forms and need to pass a property from one form to the other.

On Form 1 I have a method

```
 private void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm2= new Form2();
        WorkComplete += frmSetNewTime.btnOk_Click;
        frmSetNewTime.Show();
    }

    private void WorkComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //   Property = Property from form 2
    }
```

On Form2 I have a method called btnOK_Click

```
public void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Property = 5
     }
```

My goal is to pass the property from form2 back to form 1.

I cant subscribe WorkComplete because it is a method group is the error I get. Does anyone know the proper way, or maybe proper syntax, to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public event OnWorkCompleted;

public void WorkComplete()
{
   if(OnWorkCompleted != null)
       OnWorkCompleted(Property, null);
}
```

On the subscriber form :

```
Form1.OnWorkCompleted += Form1WorkCompleted;

public void Form1WorkCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var property = (int)sender;
    MessageBox.Show('hey form 1 property is ' + property.);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a new project with 2 forms.

2) On Form2, create a button.

3) In the button's properties, change Modifiers to **Internal**.
Normally, this is **Private**, which means only Form2 can access button1 and its properties.  Changing it to **Internal** allows any class within the assembly to access button1.  If you were to change it to **Public**, you can also allow libraries that you reference in your project to access button1 as well.

4) On Form1, add the following code within the class:

```
    Form2 frm;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create and show the form.
        frm = new Form2()
        frm.Show();

        // Assign the event handler for the button to a handler within this class.
        frm.button1.Click += this.Form2_button1_Click;
    }

    // This is the event handler that will run when you click the button on Form2.
    private void Form2_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked the button on Form 2!");
        var frmProperty = frm.Property;
    }
```

Comment: I can do that, im trying to pass a property from form2 to form1

Comment: In that case, you'd just define frm at the class level, and reference that it in the event handler.  I've updated the answer to demonstrate that.